# How to get SubType Guid for MediaExtensionManager.RegisterAudioDecoder(...)?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to write a custom decoder for a windows store app (using Media Foundation like in this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096/view/SourceCode)).
I'm at the point where I want to try to register the decoder.

As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br240991) the method to register an audio decoder looks like this:

```
public void RegisterAudioDecoder(
  string activatableClassId, 
  Guid inputSubtype, 
  Guid outputSubtype
)
```

However I do not know what I should enter as the input subtype Guid?

Where do I get the required Guid?

There are some subtype Guids predefined but they are obviously only for the formats that are already supported.
Is there any way I can get the Guid from a file of the codec I want to decode?

Answer (score 0):

In directshow it is [`{0000F1AC-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}`](http://code.google.com/p/lavfilters/source/browse/common/includes/moreuuids.h?r=bacb7df8bc81abcb78dbad164beded3f690b66db#74). The xiph decoder and the LAV splitter are using this guid.

I don't think only the decoder is enough, because you also need a MediaSource to open the flac files and read the bytestream from it!

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. Yeah I'm working on the MediaSource and ByteStreamHandler right now.